# iPhone rotation won't rotate UIWebView

Tags: iphone, rotation, landscape

My view hierarchy looks like this:

tab bar -> navigation bar -> table view -> view 1 -> view 2 (UIWebView)

How can I rotate view 2 so it can be displayed in both landscape & portrait mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres your fix...just solved the same problem. The issue is the tab bar controller is responding no to the shouldRotate method.

Ignore the advice in the apple docs and create a subclass for tab view controller.  In that subclass handle the shouldRotate

> -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
>   {
>       // Always returning YES means the view will rotate to accomodate any
>   orientation.
>       return YES; }

Heres my complete subclass
TSTabBarController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface TSTabBarController : UITabBarController {

}

@end
```

and the implementation file.

```
#import "TSTabBarController.h"


@implementation TSTabBarController
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Always returning YES means the view will rotate to accomodate any orientation.
    return YES;
}


@end
```

If you change the class in IB for the tab bar controller you should just work.

Hope this helps.
Rich