# If a tab bar has more than 5 elements, how do I detect selection of items in "more..." list?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I Tried but could not avoid having more than 5 tabs

So now my fifth tab is a "more..." tab.

I want to select switching between views so I have followed

[My UITabBarController's didSelectViewController method is not getting called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530266/my-uitabbarcontrollers-didselectviewcontroller-method-is-not-getting-called)

but set the toolbar (subclassed) as its own delegate using the tips from

[iPhone rotation won't rotate UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113748/iphone-rotation-wont-rotate-uiwebview)

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}
```

So - when I select one of the tabs I get a log message

How do I tell when one of the items in the "more..." list has been selected?
The didSelectViewController event has not been fired (as it should not because the VC is the list).